# Spring Kafka Consumer Retry

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka consumer which fetches messages from a topic and persist them into a db. If a failure condition is met , say for instance the db is unavailable , does kafka consumer library provide mechanism to retry ? If it does , is there a way to set different retry intervals such as 1st retry should be done after 5 mins , 2nd after 30 mins , 3rd after 1 hr etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring Kafka is shipped with the `RetryingMessageListenerAdapter` and `RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter`. If you use `@KafkaListener`, you can supply `AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory` with the `RetryTemplate`. And the last one can be injected with any custom `RetryPolicy` and `BackOffPolicy` from the Spring Retry project:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retrying-deliveries

Also bear in mind that since version `2.0`, there is transaction support in Spring Kafka, based on such one in the Apache Kafka `0.11.x.x`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: Thanks Artem , when I have 10 offsets say for instance in a partition. If message at offset 5 is failed to be inserted into DB , would this be tried based on the retry config that I set while offsets 6 through 10 continue to executed as part of normal process? or would consumer wait till 5 is completed successfully? I assume the message will not be committed for offset 5 until retry tries are exhausted

Comment: That's correct. Records in the same partition are processed sequentially and, therefore, `6` won't be processed until `5` is successful or exhausted in retry.

Comment: Thanks , one last question. Can I enable retry only for specific types of error?

Comment: Yes, you can. That's `RetryPolicy` responsibility. See its JavaDocs and implementations.